# How to capture an event in the middle

Tags: javascript

I would like to attach a click event listener and run some action with "data-attr" at this context, as elegant as possible.

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="group" data-attr="info1">
        <div class="a-casual-class-1">***</div>
        <div class="a-casual-class-2">AAA</div>
    </div>

    <div class="group" data-attr="info2">
        <div class="a-casual-class-1">***</div>
        <div class="a-casual-class-2">AAA</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

A) Just a single event to the root (#container)

- check if event.target is a-casual-class-1 or a-casual-class-2 and get parent element to retrieve the data attribute or
- retrieve the .group element from the root and the data-attr.

B) I could get first the nodes list of '.group', make a loop and attach the event listener to each element.

Is there a better approach to handle this situation?

Comment: can you use jQuery?

Comment: My question is really related to plain JavaScript.

Comment: Did you try to solve your issue by yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A) Just a single event to the root (#container)

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` to target all the internal divs.

> B) I could get first the nodes list of '.group', make a loop and attach the element.

When you make a selector it will give you an array like object of dom nodes. You have to loop through them and bind the events.

So the overall idea is, as *events* are tend to bubble up in the DOM, you can bind the event on the `#container`'s child divs. Now whenever you click on the child divs of `.group` it will always find the div which got the event bound and just executes the callback.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#container > div');

// divs.forEach(function(div){ // it worked at chrome 57
[].forEach.call(divs, function(div){ // changed if user is on old version of browser
  div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var data = this.dataset.attr;
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="group" data-attr="info1">
    <div class="a-casual-class-1">***</div>
    <div class="a-casual-class-2">AAA</div>
  </div>

  <div class="group" data-attr="info2">
    <div class="a-casual-class-1">***</div>
    <div class="a-casual-class-2">AAA</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer. There 's a small problem with the query selector. The `querySelectorAll` method returns a NodeList object. You can 't access it directly with `forEach`. One simple solution could be using `Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(div) { ... });`

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I tried with a classic for loop but I had to pack the event listener in a closure, with forEach seems to work, doesn't? It may good work if the list of elements is small, because of performance, right?

Comment: Yep at chrome _57.0.2987.133 (Official Build) (32-bit)_ it is working fine...;) @AlexSlipknot

Comment: @Jai, Ok then run it on other browser like FF or Edge ;)

Comment: @AlexSlipknot that's fine updated it with some comments.

Comment: Nice. And what's about performance explanation? And what if inside container will be spans for example :) Maybe selector might be an asterisk?

Comment: @AlexSlipknot That won't be expensive if you see the current structure.

Comment: Yes, In Edge corrected code works. But not previous.

Comment: The answer works fine in modern browsers as the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) says. For older browsers like Internet Explorer use the array prototype call.

Comment: NodeList.forEach(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility

Answer (score 1):

> A) Just a single event to the root (#container)

If the structure is not too complex, then you could bind the event to the root and check the class of `event.target` to run your action.

> check if event.target is a-casual-class-1 or a-casual-class-2 and get
>   parent element to retrieve the data attribute or retrieve the .group
>   element from the root and the data-attr.

Instead of checking for `a-casual-class-1`, you could check for the parent's class and then take the action.

**For Example:**

```js
var target = document.getElementById('container');
target.addEventListener('click', doAction);

function doAction(e) { 
  if (e.target.className === 'group') {
    console.log(e.target.dataset.attr);
  }
  if (e.target.parentElement.className === 'group') {
    console.log(e.target.parentElement.dataset.attr);
  } 
}
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 12p; padding: 12px;
  border: 4px solid #b33;
}
.group {
  margin: 12px; padding: 12px;
  border: 4px solid #33b; 
}
.group > div { background-color: #ddd; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="group" data-attr="info1">
    <div class="a-casual-class-1">***</div>
    <div class="a-casual-class-2">AAA</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group" data-attr="info2">
    <div class="a-casual-class-1">***</div>
    <div class="a-casual-class-2">AAA</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> B) I could get first the nodes list of '.group', make a loop and
>   attach the event listener to each element.

If your markup and structure gets complex, then it would be better to iterate through your `.groups` using `querySelectorAll` and then bind the event to each one of those. This is what is shown in the other answer.

---

*Bottomline: Just see if your code starts getting too complex depending on the complexity of your markup structure. Also, you need to consider if you have other event handlers bound to the siblings and/or children nested in the `#container`. In that case, you might find yourself fiddling with `capture` and/or `stopPropagation`.*